# Capture images from webcam in c#

Tags: c#, webcam, qr-code, webcam-capture

I've been working on an application which generates and reads(decode) QR codes. In decoding part the user capture the picture of QR code and the program will start process of decoding.
My problem is I don't Know how I can take the photo.
P.S:
If you offer a library please give a link which contains the tutorial of using that lib.
Thank you.

Comment: Library advice is off-topic for SO, try searching the web for "C# library webcam capture".

Comment: I've searched but I couldn't find tutorials

Comment: @A.Hajeb At least pick some library, try to use it and if you encounter any difficulties, then create a specific question about how to use that specific library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for web cam recording since a long time, you can use Aforge.NET .

Here is code for the same using WPF :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection VideoCaptureDevices;
        private VideoCaptureDevice FinalVideo;
        public VideoFileWriter writer= new VideoFileWriter();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            VideoCaptureDevices = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
            foreach (FilterInfo VideoCaptureDevice in VideoCaptureDevices)
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(VideoCaptureDevice.Name);
            }
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;


        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            writer.Open(@"d:\\newVid.avi", 640, 480, 25, VideoCodec.MPEG4);

            FinalVideo = new VideoCaptureDevice(VideoCaptureDevices[comboBox1.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            FinalVideo.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalVideo_NewFrame);
            FinalVideo.Start();

        }

        void FinalVideo_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {

            System.Drawing.Image imgforms = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();

            BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
            bi.BeginInit();

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imgforms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            bi.StreamSource = ms;
            bi.EndInit();            

            //Using the freeze function to avoid cross thread operations 
            bi.Freeze();

            //Calling the UI thread using the Dispatcher to update the 'Image' WPF control         
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(delegate
            {
                pictureBox1.Source = bi; /*frameholder is the name of the 'Image' WPF control*/
            }));

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                writer.WriteVideoFrame(bmp);
            }

        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            writer.Close();
            FinalVideo.Stop();
            this.Close();
        }

    }
```

include below namespaces:

```
using AForge.Video;
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video.FFMPEG;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using AForge.Video.VFW;
```

You can set change frame rate as per your convenience.

Comment: does it take a picture or capture a video?

Comment: its capturing a video, but as you can see in code there are images which are being added in as frame. you can pick any image .

Comment: VS doesn't recognize "BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();"

Comment: You will find it in PresentationCore.dll library. This class is in System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace.